# How can I calculate a running average using Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, aggregation

I am very new to Apache Kafka. I am trying to build a streams application that calculates a running average of the input stream. In its current form, my code calculates the running sum and the number of records (grouped by key), and stores them in separate KStreams.

I verified that these two streams contain the correct values by publishing them to separate topics and viewing the results using a Console Consumer. In order to complete the application, I need to divide the value of the "runningSum" stream by the value of the "numberOfRecords" stream, and publish the resulting stream to a new topic.

Thanks for your help!

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Reducer;

public class RunningAverage {
    static String INPUT_TOPIC = "input";
    static String OUTPUT_TOPIC = "average";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "running-average");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Double().getClass());

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        final KStream<String, Double> inputStream = builder
                .stream(INPUT_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()));

       KStream<String, Long> numberOfRecords = inputStream.groupByKey()
            .count(Materialized.as("NumberOfRecords"))
            .toStream();
            

        // Sourced from
        // https://dev.to/itnext/how-to-use-stateful-operations-in-kafka-streams-4ia1
        KStream<String, Double> runningSum = inputStream.groupByKey()
            .reduce(new Reducer<Double>() {
                @Override
                public Double apply(Double currentSum, Double v) {
                    Double summation = (currentSum + v);
                    return summation;
                }
            }).toStream();
            
        final Topology topology = builder.build();

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
                new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        streams.close();
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                });
        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's easier to create a rolling average of time windows, not a running average total, because this will not work across application resets. Otherwise, what difficulty are you having with querying your statestore during the summation? Note: unless all keys are the same, the `numberOfRecords` is only summed per unique key, not just one value for overall number of records

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will look into implementing a rolling average of time windows. I'm vaguely familiar with the term "querying the statestore". I believe that is the process of accessing the latest record in the `numberOfRecords` stream, right? I will look into that as well.

Comment: That's correct. This page should help getting data in the store https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html One alternative is to reset the consumer every run (or disable commits), then add a simple record counter+sum variable in the consumer, rather than use a store, but that'll only work for one instance of the app/single partitioned topic